# XOpenDisplay fails in OS X

Tags: macos, x11

I am trying to run an applicatoin that uses X11.  The application tries to make a call to XOpenDisplay(NULL), but it always returns NULL.  I have set the DISPLAY environment variable set to :0 and the XAUTHORITY environment variable set to ~/.Xauthority.  I am not familiar with X11 - is there anything else I need to do to make this call work?

Comment: Are you running your app from Terminal.app or xterm (started via X11.app)?

Comment: I have tried both, with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the X server? /Applications/Utilities/X11.app

Comment: Yes I have.  I was thinking that the X server had to be running in order to connect to it, so I tried running it and then running my application, but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used X, but perhaps "xhost +localhost" or just "xhost +" as a sanity check, but that latter has security issues.